# How to create a vector to store data

Tags: r

I have created this simple asset growth model and get 225 points. Only problem is I would like to repeat this 10 times, basically store the first 225 points and repeat the process again this time changing only the standard normal random variable, here is what is have done

```
St <- 10
u <- 0.15
sigma <- 0.1
h <- seq(0,1,by=1/225)
t <- h[-1]

for (j in 1:10) {
  z <- rnorm(225)  
  for (i in 1:225){
     ST <- St*exp((u-0.5*(sigma^2))*t - sigma*z[j]*sqrt(t))
  }
}
```

Comment: St <- 10
u <- 0.15
sigma <- 0.1
h <- seq(0,1,by=1/225)
t <- h[-1]

for (j in 1:10) {
  z <- rnorm(225)  
  for (i in 1:225){
    ST <- St*exp((u-0.5*(sigma^2))*t - sigma*z[j]*sqrt(t))
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm if my calculation is correct:

```
St <- 10
u <- 0.15
sigma <- 0.1
z <- rnorm(225) 
h <- seq(0,1,by=1/225)
t <- h[-1]

List = list()
for (i in 1:225){
  S <- St * exp( (u - 0.5 * (sigma^2)) * t[i] - sigma * z[i] * sqrt(t[i]) )
  List[[i]] = S
} 

Matrix = do.call(rbind, List)
Matrix
```

If it is, then do you want to do the same 10 times?
Since you are not responding, I am going to go ahead and assume that this is what you want. Here is the code:

```
St <- 10
u <- 0.15
sigma <- 0.1
h <- seq(0,1,by=1/225)
t <- h[-1]

BigList = list()
for (g in 1:10){

  z <- rnorm(225) 
  List = list()
  for (i in 1:225){
    S <- St * exp( (u - 0.5 * (sigma^2)) * t[i] - sigma * z[i] * sqrt(t[i]) )
    List[[i]] = S
  } 

  BigList[[g]] = do.call(rbind, List)
}
All = do.call(cbind, BigList)
All
```

Comment: Hi @AK88, thank you very much. Its brilliant, it works

Comment: Hey, wish i could. But it says "votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicity displayed post score."

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully you will figure everything out soon :))